# Line stepping through is slow by pressing F10

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Has anyone noticed that when debugging a code line by line by pressing F10, the yellow highlight is moving much slower than VS2012? It has to wait like a second to move to the next line when pressing F10. Line by line.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was caused by the .NET Reflector Visual Studio Extension.

I tried to disable all options, but only disabling it worked. Step over debugging is now back to normal and doesn't sometimes take 2-3 retries before moving to the next line.

Disable it in Tools / Extensions and Updates.

Comment: I didn't have the .NET Reflector installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Installing Visual Studio Update 1 fixed it for me.

Sire's solution worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the LastPass installation/extension. Uninstalling fixes the problem.

See this thread [Visual Studio 2010 F10/F11 Stepping Slow, Toolbar Stepping Fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623270/visual-studio-2010-f10-f11-stepping-slow-toolbar-stepping-fine)